# How to fix recent node.js errors from my apps?

Tags: node.js, express, console

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
var hbs = require("express-handlebars");
const morgan = require("morgan");

const middlewares = require("./middlewares/middlewares");

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3002;
var app = express();
// setup static file service
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "static")));
//Setup app port
app.set("port", process.env.PORT || PORT);
// setup handlebars and the view engine for res.render calls
app.set("view engine", "html");
app.engine(
  "html",
  hbs({
    extname: "html",
    defaultView: "default",
    layoutsDir: __dirname + "/views/layouts/",
    partialsDir: __dirname + "/views/partials/"
  })
);

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Hello world");
});

app.use(morgan("common"));
app.use(middlewares.errorHandler);
app.use(middlewares.ignoreFavicon);
app.use(middlewares.notFound);

var server = app.listen(app.get("port"), () =>
  console.log(`Server started...Listening on port: ${PORT}`)
);
```

This is my basic server setup. Whenever I request a route I get the following errors in my console. I had to add middleware ignoring this route as well. "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1"

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at Function.keys ()
    at contentscript.bundle.js:72
    at S.Object.isExtensible.Object.isExtensible.e.___hb.e.___hb (contentscript.bundle.js:29)

[Honeybadger] Unable to send error report: no API key has been configured.

Answer (score 0):

is there more of a stack trace? Also, when you say "console", do you mean in the Node console, or in the browser console? It looks like the log message is from our [client-side JavaScript package](https://github.com/honeybadger-io/honeybadger-js), which I would expect in the browser. If you're catching errors in your Node application, you should use our [Node.js package](https://github.com/honeybadger-io/honeybadger-node).

In honeybadger.js, `___hb` can sometimes appear in stack traces because the function was wrapped by our library, but the error is often still in your project code. I would suggest configuring Honeybadger with an API key if you're trying to diagnose errors in production.

Related docs:

- https://docs.honeybadger.io/lib/javascript/index.html
- https://docs.honeybadger.io/lib/node.html